# With next.js, why did I suddenly start seeing Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'?

Tags: node.js, webpack, next.js

I changed nothing, but am using `"next": "9.4.4"`, and I see:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'web/node_modules/graceful-fs'
Could not find files for /app/d/[id] in .next/build-manifest.json
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'web/node_modules/graceful-fs'
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're not in an `/api` directory. The client side code won't be able to import `fs`, only the API files will

Comment: But I'm not using `fs` anywhere

Comment: Hmm that's strange. When stuff like this happens I usually delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` again. On one occasion, I had to reinstall node.js which fixed the issue

Comment: Did all that. Maybe I'll try a different version of node?

Answer (score 1):

Your component might be rendering on the client-side. Check that places you assume are rendered on the server (`getStaticProps`/`getServerSideProps`) might be hydrating your component and trying to run code you think should run on the server actually on the client.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the following problem:
Could not find files for /events in .next/build-manifest.json error in next js and also it was complaining about  *“import fs from…”*

it seems that the problem was happening because I had a function using fs outside the getStaticProps.
As soon as nested the fs call inside the **getStaticProps()**, it worked fine.

Comment: Hi, this isn't an answer, its another question. Welcome and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)